# JS: history.pushState not working in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pushstate

I'm trying to wrap my head around history.pushState functionality, it works if I use it in console but won't produce the desired results in a function on the page or in a jsfiddle.
 [JSFIDDLE LINK HERE!](http://jsfiddle.net/tCQzJ/1/)

HTML:

```
<a href="#1" id="#1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#2" id="#2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#3" id="#3">Link 3</a>
<a href="#4" id="#4">Link 4</a>
<a href="#5" id="#5">Link 5</a>
<a href="#6" id="#6">Link 6</a>
<a href="#7" id="#7">Link 8</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    var linkhref = $(this).attr("href");
    var base = document.location;
    var stateObj = { test: "page" };
//  alert(linkhref);     /*make sure href is link we want*/

    history.pushState(stateObj, 'New URL: '+linkhref, base+linkhref);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I've also tried the simpler 
history.pushState(stateObj, 'Test', linkhref); with the same no result.

I've tried to copy the Mozilla documentation [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) but can't get anything to work outside of manually pasting the history.pushState line into console.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it worked fine. Doesn't work on JSFiddle though for some reason. Unless there's some other problem somewhere else, I can't see the reason why it doesn't work.